# How to preserve "counter" variable across multiple server instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, architecture, load-balancing

We're setting up the back-end architecture for our mobile application to connect to, but we need some help. Our application is built to mimic "take a number" tickets you would see at a deli or pharmacy. Users will use our mobile application to send a request to our node controller and our node controller will respond with a spot number.

We currently have our node controller set up on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and have enabled load balancing to handle any surges in requests. Our question is: how do we persist our `spotNumber` across multiple instances of our node controller? We have it built now as a local variable that starts at 1 and increments with each request, but will this persist if AWS spins up a new instance of our node controller to handle increased traffic? If not, what would be the best practice for preserving our `spotNumber` across all potential instances of our server?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a database.

Clearly you can't store the value within the node application, not only due to scaling but to prevent data loss if the application shuts down unexpectedly.

It sounds like you don't already have a database, so DynamoDB might be a good choice, as long as your only use case is to share a counter between applications. You can find an example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.04).

You could also use [Redis on Elasticache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/GettingStarted.html), but I think that it's overkill for a single counter.

Comment: We do have a DynamoDB instance set up! We thought about doing this, but figured that it would be too inefficient. For each app request, we would have to make two calls to the database right? One call to query the current spot number then another to increment it

Comment: @ZacClark you only need to make one request... in the example, `ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"` returns the value, in the response, as it stands after the update.  You never want to read, then increment (locally), then write, because two concurrent requests will end up with the same value (if the ordering turns out to be read 1, read 2, write 1, write 2 -- that's a race condition).  Letting DynamoDB do the +1 math avoids this, because concurrent requests will not interfere with each other's atomicity.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping accurate counters at different scales may require different implementations. At small scale, a simple session variable and locking logic in the application would be enough. However, at a larger scale session synchronization and locking is better managed with a database. In particular for your case, [DynamoDB conditional writes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate) or [Redis counters](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-5-using-redis-for-application-support/5-2-counters-and-statistics/) seems useful. However, keep your requirements simple and clear, managing counters at scale may require algorithms and data structures with funny names, like the [HyperLogLog](https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/counting/hyperloglog/).